# Sharp installs via npm on Windows 10 x64, but gatsby develop does not find procedure \sharp.node

Tags: node.js, windows, npm-install, sharp

I have installed the windows-build-tools and node-gyp. Installing the gatsby-plugin-sharp did work:

```
+ sharp@0.23.0
+ gatsby-plugin-sharp@2.2.22
+ gatsby-transformer-sharp@2.2.14
added 255 packages from 219 contributors, removed 4 packages, updated 6 packages and audited 31172 packages in 77.277s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I had only 2 warnings:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

But if I start gatsby develop, I get an error:

```
PS D:\Projekte\gatsby\projectname> gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.260 s

Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
\\?\D:\Projekte\gatsby\projectname\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-manifest\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node

- Remove the "node_modules/sharp" directory, run "npm install" and look for errors
- Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/
- Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues
```

I did remove the folder and made "npm install", but this does not work. The file sharp.node is there, but what does "\\?\" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the gatsby-plugin-sharp and gatsby-plugin-manifest and gatsby-image and made npm install with an empty cache. This worked. There are args now in the package.json of the sharp module:

```
"_args": [
      [
        "sharp@0.23.0",
        "D:\\Projekte\\gatsby\\projectname"
      ]
    ],
```

Seams that something got broken by installing sharp (not necessary) after the gatsby-plugin-sharp.